# What can I do with the top secret folder?

Tags: 7.62-high-calibre

I'm playing the unmodded European version of the game, and I suspect the mission "Top Secret" is either bugged or made it into the game in an unfinished state.

I've successfully taken over the base and captured the documents. At this point, the game suggests that I can return them to Lond (but it's probably a bad idea), or give them to someone else. And sure enough, Puerto Viejo seems to be enjoying quite an influx of tourists when I arrive.

Who else can I give the documents to? I've already tried Sosa's administration in Artrigo (barring Sosa himself, who won't talk to me at this point), Tanya's rebels in their camp, and Emilio Calderon: no-one has a dialogue option regarding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one of russian fan-sites I find that:

> Q: What to do with the secret documents and manual for "Boeing-747"?
>
> A: If you killed Lond, documents may have another use when one of the
>   key figures of the conflict will have serious problems with the
>   government of the United States. Flight manual for "Boeing" just an
>   easter egg ;-)

[Source](http://teragame.ru/tags/7.62/)

Comment: Thanks. So an opportunity only presents itself much later in the game, and Lond's sudden betrayal is inevitable?

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann if you complete this quest fast, Lond just dissapeared and you'll be attacked at random encounter. Otherwise you'll be attacked at this bar by Lond and his men.